# How to texturize a large terrain with few PBR maps?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have seen that there is a very effective technique to texturize large terrains. The concept is quite simple and no huge maps are needed. The first map is used to cover the whole terrain area, then, a second map is added to create medium distance detail and finally a third map is configured only for small details, I think sometimes only two maps are enough if those are well combined. All this in a single material.

I could create a couple materials with the Node-Wrangler but I was unable to combine both. I'm using PBR materials, including displacement maps.

May someone tell me where can I find a Blender tutorial which explain about this kind of master material?

Thank you for your help.

—Joe

Comment: Hi :). This could help: [Blender Guru - How to Tile a Texture Without Repetition](https://youtu.be/-VgtSL5ZpYc)

Comment: There is also Blender Guru's [Abandoned House - Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aNnERnHRZg) which covers a lot of mixing different PBR materials.

Comment: Hello, Jachym Michal and Blunder! 
Thank you very much for your help!
I will take a look to those tutorials.